# How to keep line breaks within pre Tag with TYPO3 CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

I'm using TYPO3 9.5 with CKEditor extension.

Trying to add code blocks using the `pre` Tag does not work for me.
E.g. inserting the following HTML via source View:

```
<pre>
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'GeorgRinger.news',
    'Recent',
    [
        'News' =&gt; 'list',
    ],
    [],
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT
);
</pre>
```

Results in the following after saving the content element:

```
<pre>
  \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(          'GeorgRinger.news',          'Recent',          [              'News' =&gt; 'list',          ],          [],          \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT      );</pre>
```

I can not find a single information regarding which configuration needs to be adjusted, or what's causing the removal of line breaks.

Adding `<br>` tags at end of each line works once. But they are removed when the form is loaded again. Even after adding them explicitly:

```
processing:
    allowTagsOutside:
        - pre
        - blockquote
        - ul
        - ol
        - li
        - br
```

This issue occurs only, if the `pre` Tag is inside an `ol > li` structure. On root level, there is not even a need for `<br>`, a linke break will be enough an kept.

Comment: Do you have a `<f:spaceless>` wrapping your template ? If yes, try to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the breaks are already removed when storing back to the database. So even RTE will not show them on 2nd load.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the CKEditor configuration and created a code format configuration. It's working for me. You will need to override **Processing.yaml** and **Default.yaml**

**1) Add configuration in Processing.yaml**

- Check `pre` tag allowed in the `allowTags:`
- Add HTML parsing fo Database, check the code below:

  ```
  processing:
      HTMLparser_db:
          tags:
              pre:
                  rmTagIfNoAttrib: false
  ```

**2) Add the style set for code format**

```
editor:
    config:
        contentsCss: "EXT:site_builder/Resources/Public/Css/rte.css"
        stylesSet:
            - { name: "Code Format", element: "pre" }
```

This working fine for me. what I notice is you will need to past code as HTML. If you add the code as plain text, this will render it in a single line code and will render the same.

See CKEditor:

[image]

Instead, if you past the code format, the editor will detect `pre` tag and format as a code block, see the image below:

[image]

In the frontend, you can see the code block, see:

[image]

Hope this help you!

Comment: My issue only occurs when using pre within ol > li. Pure pre is working.

Still with your configuration, the following is saved to the DB:

<ol>     <li>     <p>Register plugin within ext_localconf.php:</p>     <pre> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(     'Ge orgRinger.news',     'Recent',     ['News' =&gt; 'list'],     [],     \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::PLUGIN_TYPE_CONTENT_ELEMENT );< /pre>     </li>

Without any linebreaks.